# how does pastie or any other site remember browser info

Tags: webbrowser-control, remember-me

I am trying to make a simple experimental app.  I'd like for it to behave like pastie.

On [pasite](http://pastie.org/) you can paste code and it will remember your browser.

So if you paste the url (that pastie provides) in the same browser then you'll be able to edit the page. Everyone else will not see the edit link.  Basically there is no registration or logging in.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [HTTP cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookies).